# Is it possible to simplify max(max(a,b),c)?

Tags: neural-networks, linear-algebra

Like the title says, is there any way to simplify the piece wise linear function of max(max(a,b),c) into some linear combination of max(a,b), max(b,c), max(a,c)?

Answer (score 1):

We are looking for coefficients $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$ such that
$$
\max(\max(a,b), c)=\alpha_1 \max(a, b) + \alpha_2 \max(a, c) +\alpha_3 \max(b, c) 
$$
for all $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$.
Let's consider some simple cases.

First, suppose $a=b=c=1$. We then have
$$
1 = \max(\max(1,1), 1)=\alpha_1 \max(1, 1) + \alpha_2 \max(1, 1) +\alpha_3 \max(1, 1) = \alpha_1 +\alpha_2 +\alpha_3.
$$
Now suppose $a=b=1$ and $c=2$, we then have
$$
2=\max(\max(1,1), 2)=\alpha_1 \max(1, 1) + \alpha_2 \max(1, 2) +\alpha_3 \max(1, 2) = \alpha_1 +2\alpha_2 +2\alpha_3.
$$
Hence, $\alpha_1 = 0$. Note that we could've set $a=c=1$ and $b=2$ as well. So by the same argument, we must have $\alpha_2=0$. And $\alpha_3 =0$...

So no, we cannot express the formula as linear combination of pairwise max functions.